# How to detect WP8 resolution at run-time from a background agent

Tags: windows-phone-8

Maybe it's right under my nose but I can't find it. How do you detect the WP8 resolution at run-time when it's from a background agent?

There's MSDN multi-resolution article that provides a way, but it uses the App object:

```
App.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor
```

I don't think this object is available in a background agent.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible from within the background agent, but you can detect the resolution when the app is first launched and store it in **IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings**. Then you can use these values in your background agent.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did, but it feels like a crude workaround. Thanks